# Configure a SQL Server Instance as (local)

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, local

Each member of our development team has a copy of our application's database running on a local version of SQL Server 2008 Enterprise with SP1. Everyone is able to access the database by specifying their server and instance name in their web.config file, but to best share the developer version of our web.config file, we have standardized on making connections strings generic by using integrated security and setting server property to (local). This strategy is working fine for the majority of our 64-bit Windows 7 machines but in few cases (local) isn't recognized. We have compared settings via the SQL Server Configuration Manager (namely ensuring that the named pipes protocol was enabled) and we've tried setting the "(local)" alias via SQL Server Client Network Utility, but we haven't any luck. What needs to be done in order to use (local) in our connections strings?

Comment: Do these computers have more than one SQL Server engine running (say an Express edition as well as the enterprise one)? In such cases, you need to specify an instance name as well.

Comment: I thought `(local)` always used shared memory.

Comment: Good questions. Only SQL Server 2008 is running. SQL Express is installed but not running.

Comment: @Oded - I thought that if `(local)` was used or `.` rather than the machine name it would always use the shared memory protocol rather than named pipes for example. I think I read that years ago on a SQL Server Performance site so it may well be entirely wrong!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Trying changing the Pipe Name for your instance to "\.\pipe\sql\query".

You can find that setting by starting SQL Server Configuration Manager, and navigating to SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for (Instance Name) and right-clicking on Named Pipes and selecting Properties. If Named Pipes is not enabled, be sure to enable it before restarting the SQL Server service (see comment by @NoahHeldman).

When connecting to the default instance (that is, without an instance name), SQL Server uses the default port of 1433 and the default pipe name of "\.\pipe\sql\query". Changing it back to match should (hopefully) fix it.

Comment: Yep. That did it. Thanks for the help, Geoff. You're already a welcomed addition to SO in my book.

Comment: I had the same issue on a machine and that worked for me as well.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried these same steps, and ended up getting a bunch of errors when trying to start the SQL Server Service, including "Server named pipe provider failed to listen on [ \\.\pipe\sql\query ]. Error: 0x57".  This happened because Named Pipes was Disabled when I tried to start the service.  To fix, just put the old value back in the pipe name field (something like \\.\pipe\mssql$<InstanceName>\sql\query), start and stop the service, then replace with \\.\pipe\sql\query and start the service again.  At least, that worked for me...

Answer (score 2):

Those machines where the database connection as (local) doesn't work is probably that way because during the database installation, the instance name was set to something specific, rather than the default of "default instance". You can change these instance names, which may resolve this issue: http://coderjournal.com/2008/02/how-to-change-instance-name-of-sql-server/.

I think this occurs when you have SQL Server Express already installed and running, and then install SQL Server Developer Edition / Standard / etc....not 100% sure though, but from what I recall, that may be the case.

Comment: Good suggestions. I tried changing the instance name but that didn't do it. I'm leaning toward your latter comment at the moment. On working machines, either Express isn't installed or we believe it was installed after the full version of SQL.